# is there some kind of expression evaluation within list/tuple slicing syntax within Python?

Tags: python, list, expression, tuples, slice

with numpy arrays, you can use some kind of inequality within the square bracket slicing syntax:

```
>>>arr = numpy.array([1,2,3])
>>>arr[arr>=2]
array([2, 3])
```

is there some kind of equivalent syntax within regular python data structures?  I expected to get an error when I tried:

```
>>>lis = [1,2,3]
>>>lis[lis > 2]
2
```

but instead of an exception of some type, I get a returned value of 2, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

p.s. I couldn't find the documentation for this syntax at all, so if someone could point me to it for numpy and for regular python(if it exists) that would be great.

Comment: I have next to no NumPy knowledge, but I think the behaviour you observe is nothing special, simply resulting from two fact: (1) You can broadcast comparisions like everything else, resulting in a `bool` array, and (2) you can use a [`bool` array as index](http://numpy.org/).

Comment: `numpy.array` probably defines a comparision with an `int` which returns some special object which in turn can be used as an index for the array. The array type then extracts the comparison type and operand from this object and returns a new array with matching elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 2.x `lis > 2` returns `True`. This is because the operands have different types and there is no comparison operator defined for those two types, so it compares the class names in alphabetical order (`"list" > "int"`). Since `True` is the same as `1`, you get the item at index 1.

In Python 3.x this expression would give you an error (a much less surprising result).

```
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

To do what you want you should use a list comprehension:

```
[x for x in lis if x > 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

use list comprehension:

```
[a for a in lis if a>=2]
```